# ggplot2: two discrete variables + percentage of cases + continuos variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a plot with a discrete variable on x axis and another discrete variable on y axis, with points that are colored by the mean of `val` and sized by the proportion of cases in `x`.

The data looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(y=c("a","b","c","a","d","a","a","c","d","a","b","c","a","d","a","a","c","d","d","a","b","c","a","d","a","a","c","d"),
                  x=c("x","y","z","t","r","x","x","x","y","z","t","r","r","x","y","z","t","r","x","x","y","z","t","r","r","x","r","x"),
                  val=c(1,4,1,6,3,6,2,7,8,2,5,7,2,8,5,8,6,4,2,4,5,7,6,5,4,4,3,3))
```

I have tried with geom_count and with the following:

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=val))+
  stat_sum(aes(size=..prop.., group=x))+
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10)
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQxFg.png)

But there must be some weird overrides I am unaware of. The props produced in the size parameter are not correct, as if I remove fill variable from the plot they are different. Can anyone help me? I have scrutinized google but I have not find any solutions.

Comment: What do you actually want to show at each (x, y) location? The sum of `val`? What should the size of the point be showing, and what should the color represent? The `fill` for a point will only show up if you use a point type that has a fill, like `shape = 21`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, indeed I want to represent the mean of `val`, and the size should be the proportion of cases for each `y` grouped by `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to compute the counts, percentages and the mean for the fill value outside of `ggplot` and using `geom_point` to plot the aggregated data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 |> 
  group_by(x, y) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), val = mean(val)) |> 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) |> 
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'x'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, size = pct, fill = val)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10)
```

[image]